# why does bufio.NewReader does not work proprely when input come from redirection?

Tags: shell, go, input, pipe

I am currently trying to solve [this challenge](https://www.codechef.com/problems/COVID19B) on the website CodeChef when entering input manually I get the expected answer for the problem like stated in the problem.

But when I tried to use `cat in.txt | go run my_program.go` the output from my program is different.

As you can see I tried to debug using `fmt.Printf` and it look like `bufio.NewReader` randomly miss the input from the pipe.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and if there are alternative approach to read a whole line containing multiple integrers in Golang.

**Thanks you for helping me !**

content of `in.txt` :

```
4
3
1 2 3
3
3 2 1
3
0 0 0
3
1 3 2
```

normal output when entering input manually :

```
1 1
3 3
1 1
1 2
```

output with debug message when entering text using `cat in.txt | go run my_program.go`

```
debug <1 2 3
>
1 1
debug <>
1 1
debug <>
1 1
debug <>
1 1
```

my program :

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "strings"
        "bufio"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {
    t, n := 0, 0
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &t)
    for i := 0; i < t; i++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &n)
            v := make([]int, n)
            rd := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
            text, _ := rd.ReadString('\n')
            fmt.Printf("debug <%s>\n", text)
            arr := strings.Split(strings.TrimSuffix(text, "\n"), " ")
            for k := 0; k < len(arr); k++ {
                    v[k], _ =  strconv.Atoi(arr[k])
            }
            fmt.Println(calc_intersect(v))
    }
}

func calc_intersect(v []int) (int, int) {
    smt, lgt := 100, 0
    scenario := make([]int, len(v))
    for sc := 0; sc < len(v); sc++  {
            infect := make([]bool, len(v))
            infect[sc] = true
            scenario[sc] = simulate(v, infect)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(scenario); i++ {
            if scenario[i] <= smt {
                    smt = scenario[i]
            }
            if scenario[i] > lgt {
                    lgt = scenario[i]
            }
    }
    return smt, lgt
}

func simulate(v []int, infect []bool) int {
            var nb_inf int = 1
            pos := make([]int, len(v))
            for time := 0; time < 25; time++ {
                    for p := 0; p < len(v); p++ {
                            pos[p] = (v[p] * time) + p
                    }
                    for a := 0; a < len(v); a++ {
                            check_intersect(pos, infect, &nb_inf, a)
                    }
            }
            return nb_inf
}

func check_intersect(pos []int, infect []bool, nb_inf *int, a int) {
            for b := 0; b < len(pos); b++ {
                    if a == b {
                            continue
                    }
                    if pos[a] == pos[b] && (infect[a] || infect[b]) && !(infect[a] && infect[b]) {
                            *nb_inf += 1
                            infect[a], infect[b] = true, true
                    }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `bufio.NewReader` is wrong. You create a new buffered reader each time through the `i` loop. The reader may read ahead if input is available, and when you don't re-use the reader that buffered input is unused.

Simply move `rd := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` outside of the loop to fix the problem.

Your code works when you read from the console via stdin because you can't type fast enough for the reader to try to buffer input.